# Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox 5.0.4 and Vagrant 1.7.4 on OSX. I am trying to setup OpenShift using Vagrant.

When I run the following command,

```
vagrant up --no-provision
```

it fails with this message

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

cannot load such file -- vagrant/command
```

I tried with 1.7.1 but it had altogether different set of issues.

Comment: Can you paste your vagrant file and config info (plug in you might use)

Comment: Vagrantfile can be found here - https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Comment: I rolled back to Vagrant 1.7.2 as mentioned in the vagrant readme on that git project but got the same error that I was getting with 1.7.1

No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

Comment: remainder of the error message below ----

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved same issue by doing following things.

**How I got Issue:**

Accidentally, I got following issue when I start my PC and run the command `vagrant up` as usual. I do some research and found that need to run command with provision. So I did it.

[image]

**Solution:**

I just run the command `vagrant halt && vagrant up --provision` and issue resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I read it's to do with the VBOX_INSTALL_PATH env var. But setting that up did not solve the problem. I finally downgraded my virtualbox to 4.3 and the vagrant started working without errors. That's for Vagrant 1.7.2. So why the vagrant 1.7.4 doesn't work with VirtualBox 5.x despite documenting the support is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by removing the VM from Virtualbox GUI, so I could launch these commands

- vagrant plugin update
- vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to check my environment variables to remove conflicting path for the system variables and the variables for my windows user profile

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to just increase the CPUs and I did just #vagrant reload. This might be helpful for others:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
vb.memory = "2048"
vb.cpus = 4
```

Answer (score -2):

If you haven't provisioned vagrant before, you can just do:

```
vagrant up
```

Comment: You should be able to run instance without any provisionning even on 1st attempt